# Trying to copy files from two directories into the third directoy

Tags: linux-networking

First, I am trying to copy all of the files from directory1 into directory3. Then, copy every file from directory2 to directory3 with conditions:
a. copy the file from directory2 which is not present in directory3 and copy files from directory 2  which will overwrite the existing version.

Comment: Consider using `rsync`.

Comment: Is part of your question missing? You mentioned conditions, but only one condition is listed.

Comment: the conditions are: 1. copy the file from directory2 which is not present in directory3 and 2. copy files from directory 2 which will overwrite the existing version.